# Logo overlaying navbar and carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a logo on top of a navbar and carousel on the top of my webpage. I can get the logo sitting on the center of the navbar, but i can't figure out how to make it larger than the navbar and overlaying the carousel above it.

[Here's a small mockup of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK2q3.png)

And here's my little bit of code that i have so far

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
<nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar transparent" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="assets/logo-final.png" width="300" alt="Logo Thing main logo"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: any update regarding the answer?

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is separate the logo from the nav container and position it absolute. Maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/qdo9mqze/2/ , its a rough draft but you get the idea. Give it some border-bottom/top either the carousel or the nav to replicate your design.

Note: now my draft is like a flag....

```
<div class="carousel"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="nav"></div>

    .carousel {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.logo{
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top:200px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.nav{
  background:green;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
}
```